GithubCopilot Memory leak in VSCode 1.93
After updating VSCode to version 1.93, I started to notice that the laptop was running slower and was starting to heat up.
I checked the activity monitor and saw Code Helper Plugin taking up more than 2GB of RAM.

I started disabling all plugins in VS code and restarting the application and after I disabled GithubCopilot - these 2 processes disappeared.
Has anyone had this problem and if so, how did you get out of this situation?


Been dealing with a similar issue for 12hs.
It all started when Intellisense got stuck loading. Resource Monitor showed 2 Code Helper (Plugin) processes that started ramping memory up > 4gb each.
After adding "typescript.tsserver.log": "verbose"  to .vscode/settings.json and opening >Typescript: Open TS Server logs, saw that vscode TS server was apparently working on Copilot responses:
const useCart = () => {\n  const context = useContext(CartContext);\n  if (!context) {\n    throw new Error('useCart must be used within a CartProvider');\n  }\n  return context;\n};",
            "projectRootPath": "/",
            "scriptKindName": "TSX"

You could try the following:

open Settings (cmd+,)
search for @ext:vscode.typescript-language-features intellisense
disable Project Wide Intellisense and Web Type Acquisition

After that, and a good-old vscode restart, such processes stopped memory leaking
